# Cannot add a regex parameter to split function

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ for some reason does not allow following line:

```
tokensX = tokensY[i].split("(\s)*");
```

It give compitalion error: `illegal escape character`
   It highlights only this part of this string: **"(\s)*"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String literal `\s` is not a valid escape sequence. You have to escape the `\`. Use `\\s`. So

```
tokensX = tokensY[i].split("(\\s)*");
```

Comment: It's a string because it's included into quotes. Why this kind of string is illegal? Why then I can declare `tokensY = sFileLines.split("\r\n");` ?

Comment: @RCola Because those are valid [escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). `\s` is not. This doesn't have anything to do with regex, _yet_.

Comment: @RCola Try using `(\\s)+`.